# DataOutputStream not emptying buffer

Tags: java, networking, outputstream

I am working on a server/client communication program and I am stuck at a problem. When I try to send messages from my client side it won't work properly. After initializing the server, I connect the client and that is successful. When I try to send messages from the client, the server won't receive them. After I close the client connection, the server receives all of the messages I attempted to send earlier. The following class is what I am using:

```
public class ServerSender extends Thread
{
    private DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    private Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void run()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            try
            {
                out.writeUTF(kb.nextLine());
                out.flush();
            } catch(IOException e) { System.out.println("error"); }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: can you provide the server code as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataOutputStream` doesn't *have* a buffer to flush, so your diagnosis is incorrect. However you need to be aware that `writeUTF()` writes a format that only `DataInputStream.readUTF()` can read. If you're trying to write lines you have the wrong API: try `BufferedWriter.write()/.newLine()`.

Comment: I see. I was using a `Scanner` to read the socket input stream. Changing the `Scanner` to `DataInputStream` fixed my problem. Thanks!